# Google app script トリガー認証時のブロックについて

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

初めまして、GoogleサポートよりAppに関する対応窓口がないので、
こちらに質問するように案内をいただき初めて投稿いたします。

スプレッドシートから問合せフォームを作成いたしまして、
Appscriptにアクセス後、フォーム送信時のイベントでトリガーを保存しようとすると、
オーナーアカウントなのに下記のメッセージがでてブロックされます。

4月7日までは問題なく登録ができていなかったのですが、
4月10日から急に症状がでております。

This app is blocked
This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.

・管理者アカウント
・Google 二段階認証 ON

恐れ入りますが、Google側の問題かと思ったのですが、
Googleヘルプサポート側では不明とのことで、
お手数ですが、ご確認いただきたいです。

Answer (score 0):

私自身は経験したことがありませんが、
エディタのプロジェクトの設定で確認できる
Google Cloud Platform（GCP）
が初期値では、「デフォルト」になっていると思いますが、
これを新しく作り直すと解決したというQ&Aが海外のサイトにありました。
私自身は実施したことがないことですのでその点をご留意ください。

[This app is blocked This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAppsScript/comments/u28bsl/this_app_is_blocked_this_app_tried_to_access/)

ここの I fixed it で始まる回答です。

Google cloudのコンソールから作成することになるようです。
説明は、エディタのプロジェクトの設定のところに

Apps Script プロジェクトでは、Google Cloud Platform を使用して承認、高度なサービス、その他の詳細が管理されます。詳しくは、[Google Cloud Platform](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects) をご覧ください。

と記載がありますので、そちらで確認してみてください。

Comment: 早速ありがとうございます。確認してみます。

Comment: お伝えいただいたご回答は別のプラットフォームのようです。説明が言葉足らずで申し訳ありません。スプレッドシート上からApp scriptを作成しておりまして、用途的にGoogleフォームの入力値を処理する際にトリガーを追加するのですが、ブロックされてトリガーが追加できない状態でございます。

Comment: あと、考えられることは、トリガーを設定しようとした関数以外にエディタに他の関数が保存されていて、その他の関数がトリガーではアクセスを許可されていない何かのデータにアクセスするようになっているなどでしょうか。